# Android: Apps cannot launch on Real Device

Tags: android

I successfully build the program, but apps does not launch in my device. Below is the message displayed in the eclipse console.

```
[2013-10-16 16:08:44 - MyFirstApp] Using default Build Tools revision 18.1.0
[2013-10-16 16:08:44 - MyFirstApp] Starting full Post Compiler.
[2013-10-16 16:08:44 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2013-10-16 16:08:44 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-10-16 16:08:44 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-16 16:08:44 - MyFirstApp] Performing sync
[2013-10-16 16:08:44 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a target device.
[2013-10-16 16:08:47 - MyFirstApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-10-16 16:08:47 - MyFirstApp] \MyFirstApp\bin\MyFirstApp.apk installed on device
[2013-10-16 16:08:47 - MyFirstApp] Done!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an entery of your activity in androidmanifest file and make it `LAUNCHER` activity using `<intent-filter>`

```
<application
.
.>

<activity android:name="activity_name"
                  .
                  .
                 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Application already deployed. No need to reinstall." You may try to uninstall and install again.

Comment: I've tried uninstall and reinstalled. My apps still not able to launch.

Comment: Have you correctly defined your launcher activity as @mukesh kumar wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem to configure the android manifest.xml file you have to set the intent-filter like this

`<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".HelloWorld" >`

`<intent-filter >`
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`
`</intent-filter>`
`</activity>`

in intent-filter  the category tell the application that this is the launcher activity and when ever the program starts.it start with this activity..

Answer (score 0):

How do you define your application package name? Probably it's in conflict with other app with same name. You can try to right click your project -> select android tools -> rename application package. make a new package name to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

if u add any target device  in androidmanifest.xml then just remove it may be then it will be work